# Rails 3 to_xml problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I'm trying to generate a simple XML feed using Rails' `to_xml`:

```
xml = {
  :id    => '1234',
  :title => 'Title',
  :url   => 'www.site.com',
  :items => items.to_xml(:skip_instruct => true, :skip_types => true, :include => :user)
}.to_xml(:root => 'feed', :skip_types => true)
```

I have two problems with this approach:

1. Everything inside `<items>` is ecscaped and renders as regular text.
2. It generates an additional `<items>` node

So the resulting `<items>` node looks like

```
<items>
 &lt;items&gt; ... &lt;/items&gt;
<items>
```

How can I make it work using just `to_xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use this syntax:

```
xml = {
  :id    => '1234',
  :title => 'Title',
  :url   => 'www.site.com',
  :items => items 
}.to_xml(:root => 'feed', :skip_types => true)
```

Any options you apply to the whole transformation should(?) apply to the items transformation.